# Sort Date with date which is in varchar getting issue in converting to date time with MM/DD/YYY

Tags: mysql, sql

There is the issue with datetime conversion currently "xl_date" have date MM/DD/YYYY

Example query:-

```
SELECT orders.*, 
  customer.id AS userid, 
  customer.login, 
  convert(datetime, orders.xl_date, 101) as ddates 
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN customer 
ON orders.userid = customers.id 
WHERE 1 
ORDER BY ddates DESC LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: You could share the sample data via sqlfiddle with us perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function. For example -

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(orders.xl_date, '%m/%d/%Y') AS as ddates FROM orders
```

Your query is -

```
SELECT
  orders.*, 
  customer.id AS userid, 
  customer.login, 
  STR_TO_DATE(orders.xl_date, '%m/%d/%Y')as ddates 
FROM orders 
  LEFT JOIN customer 
    ON orders.userid = customers.id 
WHERE
  1 
ORDER BY
  ddates DESC
LIMIT 0, 30
```